# Symfony Serialization component - serialize array with element and attribute

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

I trying to serialize an array with symfony's serialize component. 
I follow [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#the-xmlencoder) manual

How to create following xml document:

```
<foo tag="bar">baz</foo>
```

My array to serialize:

```
['foo' => [@tag => 'bar', 'baz']]
```

but it creates folowing:

```
<foo tag="bar">
    <item key="0">baz</item>
</foo>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create array in this way:

```
['foo' => ['@tag' => 'bar', '#' => 'baz']]
```